# The spectral radius is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-algebras, spectral-radius

Let $(A,\|.\|)$ be a complex unital Banach algebra. Let $r(a)$ the spectral radius of an element in $A$. Suppose the spectral radius is a norm on $A$, then does that imply that $\|a\|\leq k r(a)$ for every $a\in A$ and some $K>0$?
This is with reference to the converse of Corollary 7 [here.](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm79/sm79110.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.

Corollary 5 talks about "another norm" $\|\cdot\|_1$. That other norm is now $\|\cdot\|_\sigma$, with $k=1$.

Comment: OK. Thanks.....